# Copying array of characters in R

Tags: r

I've searched a bit and was unable to find an answer to this.

I am trying to copy an array containing characters, when I copy it I am getting numbers which correspond to the order of the levels.

I am copying from a messy spreadsheet so there are some notes and some cells are empty. As a result of this I choose the values I want by seeing if an appropriate value is in the cell with the clean vector.

```
clean <- c( "o", "f", "g", "s") #cleans


x <- character() #makes two empty vectors
y <- character()
for(i in 1:length(Data$Top.Hit.percentage)) {
  if(any(clean == Data$Agreement.Level)) {
    x[i] <- Data$Top.Hit.percentage[i]
    y[i] <- unique(Data$Agreement.Level[i]) #does not copy value
  }
}

y
```

Once y is copied I would like to change letters to numeric values 1-4. The letters correspond to taxonomic levels: order, family, genus, species. Thus, I would like them to be 1-4.

```
for (i in 1:length(y)) { #useless for now
   if (y[i] == "o") {
     y[i] <- 1
   }
   if (y[i] == "f") {
     y[i] <- 2
   }
   if (y[i] == "g") {
     y[i] <- 3
   }
   if (y[i] == "s") {
     y[i] <- 4
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example. i.e. show few lines of 'Data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of data$Agreement.level was factor (changed name of vector to data from Data)

```
> c <- character()
> c <- data$Agreement.Level
> c
```

When data$Agreement.Level is assigned to c it becomes type/mode factor

problem can be resolved like so:

```
> c <- as.character(data$Agreement.Level)
```

then undesired values can be removed as follows

```
inRem <- which(!(c %in% clean)) #gets index of b that do not contain clean
c <- c[-inRem] #removes indexes which return True from !(c %in% clean)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do a lookup/tansformation of character values to numbers using a named vector:

```
z <- 1:4
names(z) <-  c( "o", "f", "g", "s")
y <- z[y]
```